# How to Turn on slider repeat

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a website with slider that contains 5 images in the header. Problem is when images slide, at the end slider stops and nothing happens.I want to slider starts from the beginning.I tried java script changing but nothing happens. website: http://www.titanotrade.com.tr/

Comment: I can see you are using owl carousel I would recommend go and check their documentation  https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html

Comment: `loop:true` - https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html#loop

Comment: @Mosh Feu
 configs are in (http://titanotrade.com.tr/js/front-end.js) an all `loop:ture` sets but not working.

Comment: You don't have it in the instance: `$('.ts-slide-product').owlCarousel({`

Comment: @MoshFeu thanks for your time :) problem solved.

Comment: Glad to hear :)